# How to make moles work with MSBuild?

Tags: tfs, moles

I wrote some unit test cases with Moles, then i check it into TFS. But the auto build failed.
I do not have the right to install Moles on the build server. I checked the errors found that I did not check in files under MolesAssemblies dir. I think do not need check in them. they should be generated by Moles. How to resolve this problem? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install moles on the build server.

Comment: But I have no right to install on the build server.Could I add reference for some DLLs to resolve this issue? If cannot ,I think it's a big design issue.

Comment: @Jeff It's not just about dll referencing since Moles actually runs tests an a different HostAgent context.  Currently Visual Studio looks these HostAgents up via a registry key that is laid down via the Moles installer.  If you want to do something completely unsupported, you could attempt to fake the Moles install and xcopy everything to the machine, but you'll still be hacking the registry to make it work.

Comment: @Nick is spot on. The Moles assemblies are generated by the compiler.  The Moles host type determines which calls are routed through the moles assemblies.